# Atomikos, Java 8 and multiple databases

Tags: java, database, atomikos

We have an application that has been running fine with Java 7 for a few years, but have problems upgrading to Java 8. The database connections seems to be the problem.

This is the case:
The application accesses more than 200 databases. Or, technically, 200 different schemas on one database installation. We use Atomikos for the data sources. When starting up the application with Java 7, there is probably some sequential iteration over the data sources, because we have set the max pool size to 5. It takes a little bit of time, but really no issues.

When we try running with Java 8, my guess is that it tries to do everything in parallell. The application crashes on startup like this:

> 05:21:39.611 INFO  [main]
>   o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA
>   container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'database.np'
>   05:21:41.389 INFO  [main]
>   o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA
>   container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit
>   'database.np_000000000_0000' 05:21:41.796 INFO  [main]
>   o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA
>   container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit
>   'database.np_000000001_0000' 05:22:11.890 WARN  [main]
>   c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException - Connection pool exhausted - try
>   increasing 'maxPoolSize' and/or 'borrowConnectionTimeout' on the
>   DataSourceBean. 05:22:41.991 WARN  [main]
>   c.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException - Connection pool exhausted - try
>   increasing 'maxPoolSize' and/or 'borrowConnectionTimeout' on the
>   DataSourceBean. 05:22:41.998 ERROR [main]
>   o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator - HHH000319: Could not get database
>   metadata com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException: Connection pool
>   exhausted - try increasing 'maxPoolSize' and/or
>   'borrowConnectionTimeout' on the DataSourceBean.
>           at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosSQLException.throwAtomikosSQLException(AtomikosSQLException.java:46)
>   ~[transactions-jdbc-3.9.3.jar:na]
>           at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.throwAtomikosSQLException(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:90)
>   ~[transactions-jdbc-3.9.3.jar:na]
>           at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.throwAtomikosSQLException(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:85)
>   ~[transactions-jdbc-3.9.3.jar:na]
>
> So, we try the advice in the stacktrace, and increase maxPoolSize to a
>   suitable number above 200. Then we can actually start the application,
>   but... It seems like a complete overkill, and to make matters worse,
>   the application doesn't like having so many connections it doesn't
>   really use - the databases/schemas are accessed only now and then. We
>   see the following in the log:
>
> 11:08:26.970 [Atomikos:0] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceNp': connection idle for 358671ms
>   11:08:26.970 [Atomikos:0] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceNp': connection idle for 357953ms
>   11:08:26.970 [Atomikos:0] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceNp': connection idle for 357947ms
>   11:08:26.970 [Atomikos:0] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceNp': connection idle for 26425ms
>   11:08:26.970 [Atomikos:0] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceNp': current size: 1/4
>   11:08:29.983 [Atomikos:1] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceRolp': trying to shrink pool
>   11:08:29.984 [Atomikos:1] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceRolp': connection idle for
>   359790ms | (repeat 200 times...) | atomikos connection pool
>   'dataSourceRolp': connection idle for 263450ms 11:07:29.983
>   [Atomikos:1] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool - atomikos
>   connection pool 'dataSourceRolp': connection idle for 263446ms
>   11:07:29.983 [Atomikos:1] DEBUG c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool -
>   atomikos connection pool 'dataSourceRolp': connection idle for
>   263168ms 11:07:29.983 [Atomikos:1] DEBUG
>   c.a.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool - atomikos connection pool
>   'dataSourceRolp': current size: 1/208

Any thoughts? For legal reasons, we need to have the 200+ schemas separate. Other than that, we are fairly free to choose technical solutions as we want.

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? I had a quite similar issue during our database migration(From Oracle to PostgreSQL).

We defined the data source as JNDI, and to make the data source we also removed some attributed out from the jdbc interceptor.

If you are using PostgreSQL, please check the type of bean you defined for the data source too.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Will have a look at the JDBC interceptor. The database is MariaDB, basically a different version of MySQL.